# saving created tabs with their data

Tags: java, file, tabs, save, serializable

The program i am doing is a bit of a "to do list", where the user creates "tasks" that he has to do in a future. These tasks are organized in different tabs, according to what this tasks are related.

For example, i create the category(tab) with the name "Work", and under that tab i store all the tasks related to work, and so on.

The problem now is that i would like to save in a file, all the tabs that the user created, and the data that is stored in each category(tab). So when the user reopens the program, he can load that data, and modify it, or simply check the tasks that he has written.
I simply have no idea if this can be done, and if it can be done, how. During the programming course i saw a bit of serializable interface and I/O but i really don't know.

Comment: You could create separate `object` for information  present in each `tab` and `serialize` each `object` in separate `file`. When you start the GUI `deserialize` each object and fill the corresponding `tab` with the object's `fields` value.

Comment: i think i would try something like this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for local storage.
Look here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
Or maybe you could just save this in memory for the time of the session like this:

```
var tabs = new Array();
tabs['category'] = new Array();
tabs['category']['Work'] = new Array();
tabs['category']['Work'][0] = task1;
tabs['category']['Work'][1] = task2;
......
```

Data will remain until the page is reloaded.